# Table position different in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web development. I'm building a simple site using HTML and CSS. I have a page with 2 price lists made from tables. I have them both in one div and I want them on top of each other. There is a picture to the right of them. In firefox all is ok when I use absolute position, but in IE7 the picture pops up in between the two tables. I've tried floating right and left, positioning absolute and relative. Is it something to do with Quirks? I also changed the doctype to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html lang="en">
```

This a bit of my code.
HTML:

```
<div id="price">
 <table> 
  <tr>
   <th>Cutting</th>
   <th>Stylist</th>
   <th>Senior Stylist</th>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td>Men</td>
   <td>£32</td>
   <td>£35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Women</td>
    <td>£36</td>
    <td>£40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Restyle</td>
    <td>£40</td>
    <td>£45</td>
  </tr>
    <td colspan="3">student discount 10% Mon-Fri only</td>   
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <table> 
   <td>Half Head foils</td>
   <td>From £55</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Full Head foils</td>
    <td>From £75</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Colour between foils</td>
    <td>From £15</td>
  </tr>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Organic Permanent colour</td>
    <td>From £45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Semi-Permanent colour</td>
    <td>From £40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Colour correction</td>
    <td>By Quotation</td>
  </tr>  
</div>



 <div id="pricepicture">
  <img src="images/head.jpg" width="310" height="365" alt="picture of salon"/>
 </div>
```

And CSS: (My last attempt using float)

```
 #pricepicture {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #2c2e32;
  height: 365px;
  width: 310px;
  }

 #table {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  }

 #price {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  }

  td {
   text-align: left;
   padding: 0.2em;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   }

  th {
   text-align: left;
   padding: 0.2em;
   font-size: 1.1em;
   }

  tr {
   height: 20px;
   }
```

I've been searching the Stack overflow Questions for days. Please help before I throw my laptop out of the window! 
Thanks....

Comment: There are some errors in your HTML syntax. Check if you are closing correctly the `<table>` and `<tr>` inside the main table. Like in `<td colspan="3">`, you didn't open a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some HTML syntax errors. You must ensure that all tags are properly closed, and in the correct order. See the following.

```
<div id="price">
<table> 
    <tr>
        <th>Cutting</th>
        <th>Stylist</th>
        <th>Senior Stylist</th>
    </tr>  
    <tr>
        <td>Men</td>
        <td>£32</td>
        <td>£35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Women</td>
        <td>£36</td>
        <td>£40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Restyle</td>
        <td>£40</td>
        <td>£45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">student discount 10% Mon-Fri only</td>   
    </tr>
</table>

<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>Half Head foils</td>
        <td>From £55</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Full Head foils</td>
        <td>From £75</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colour between foils</td>
        <td>From £15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Organic Permanent colour</td>
        <td>From £45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Semi-Permanent colour</td>
        <td>From £40</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colour correction</td>
        <td>By Quotation</td>
    </tr>  
</table>
</div>

<div id="pricepicture">
    <img src="images/head.jpg" width="310" height="365" alt="picture of salon"/>
</div>
```